Call to Parent class method with Child Object
In the below example, validate(int counter) in parent class calls validate()  and validate() is implemented in Child class - Is there a way to say call local(parent) validate() method.
As parent class is abstract, I am not able to create object also.
abstract class Parent {
    protected boolean validate() {
        System.out.println("In Parent");
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean validate(int counter) {
        return this.validate();  // is there a way to tell to compiler - call current class validate()
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    protected boolean validate() {
        System.out.println("In Child");
        return validate(1); //call to Parent method.

        //....
    }
}

public class TT
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        Child ch = new Child();
        ch.validate();
    }
}


There is a way with MethodHandles, though it is a bit of work. You're circumventing the inheritance patterns by doing it. I would suggest doing it differently. Maybe have the parent validate call a private method.

Thanks @matt, I came to know about MethodHandles.

No. You can't do this. You work with Child object, so this refers to Child and you have no way to implement code in Parent.validate(). All you can do, is to create another private method in the Parent.
abstract class Parent {
    protected boolean validate() {
        return validateInternal();
    }

    protected boolean validate(int counter) {
        return validateInternal();
    }

    private boolean validateInternal() {
        System.out.println("In Parent");
        return true;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    protected boolean validate() {
        System.out.println("In Child");
        return validate(1); //call to Parent method.

        //....
    }
}

P.S. I believe that MethodHandles or Reflection is out of the scope of the question.

I don't want to complicate with MethodHandles & Reflection, liked above approach.Thank you.
